# Homomorphism and relative order questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

1) I have to prove that if $\exists$ a nontrivial homomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow B$, where A and B are finite and Abelian, then $|A|$ and $|B|$ are not relatively prime.

I know that $\phi(A)$ is a subgroup of $B$ and $\because$ $B$ is Abelian $\phi(A)\triangleleft B$. So I think $\phi(A) | |B|$ but I can't draw a connection between $|A|$ and $|B|$. Figured this out now. $A/Ker(\phi) \cong \phi(A)$, by Lagrange's, $|A/Ker(\phi)|$ divides $|A|$ and hence $|\phi(A)|$ divides $|A|$. Therefore, $|A|$ and $|B|$ are not relatively prime.

2) Deduce that $\exists$ a nontrivial homomorphism $B\rightarrow A$
Do we have to prove the converse of (1) because the orders are relatively prime? Figured it out. We can use the same argument as above.

Comment: (1): Show that the order of $\phi(A)$ is a divisor of $|A|$.

Comment: Made an edit, able to show for elements of A but how can I do that for the whole group A?

Comment: You can use the isomorphism theorems and Lagrange’s Theorem.

Comment: And, no, the fact that The order of $\phi(a)$ divides the order of $a$ for each $a$ does not “lead” to $|\phi(A)|$ dividing $|A|$. It’s actually the other way around.

Comment: True, was able to show $|A/N|$ divides $|A|$ and $A/N \cong \phi(A)$ and hence $\phi(A)$ dividies $|A|$. Thanks for the hint. How about part (2)?

Comment: where $N = Ker(\phi)$.